# Javascript cannot alert a dictionary

Tags: javascript

I have this dictionary that I want to alert through Javascript. But it is not getting alerted.Can someone please help ?

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      {% if dict %}
  <script>
       dict = {"iname": name, "imodel": dtls2};
      for (i in dict) {
          alert("Name: " + i + " Value: " + dict[i]);

      }


  </script>
     {% endif %}
     <head>
```

Comment: Check your browser console to see the error. You never defined `dtls2` (and you shouldn't use `name` either, that'll refer to `window.name`, which is almost certainly undesirable)

Comment: Just check the error from the browser console.

Comment: Thanks you are right . I didnt define some of them

Answer (score 0):

You need check the browser console error by F12 - console tab.

I tried reproduce it work

```js
var name = "A", dtls2="B";
       dict = {"iname": name, "imodel": dtls2};
      for (i in dict) {
          alert("Name: " + i + " Value: " + dict[i]);

      }
```